# .git folder contains 460 MB pack file

Tags: git

I am having 450MB file in my .git/objects/pack folder,which is creating problem in cloning the repo.

I have tried all possible solution mentioned in stackoverflow,but nothing seems to work.

> git count-objects -v

```
count: 1
size: 4
in-pack: 172597
packs: 1
size-pack: 469615
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
size-garbage: 0
```

> du -sch .[!.]* *

```
 460M   .git
4.0K    .gitignore
2.3M    .idea
```

Comment: What do you want? The pack file contains the history (i.e. commits, versioned files, etc) of your project. You want to change the history to reduce versioned files? Or [shallow clone](https://www.perforce.com/ja/blog/141218/git-beyond-basics-using-shallow-clones)?